# Resolve a Dictionary with UnityContainer

Tags: c#, prism, unity-container, containers

I'm just having doubt about this small interface.

I have the following interface, this is for register some items to map itemsViewModel in each module. So each module will register some keys.

```
public interface IExerciseMap
{
    Dictionary<Type, Func<BaseItem, BaseItemViewModel>> Maps { get; }
    void AddExercise(Type type, Func<BaseItem, BaseItemViewModel> func);
}

public class ExerciseMap : IExerciseMap
{
    public Dictionary<Type, Func<BaseItem, BaseItemViewModel>> maps;

    public void  AddExercise(Type type, Func<BaseItem,BaseItemViewModel> func)
    {
        maps.Add(type, func);
    }

    public Dictionary<Type, Func<BaseItem, BaseItemViewModel>> Maps
    {
        get
        {
            if (maps == null)
                maps = new Dictionary<Type, Func<BaseItem, BaseItemViewModel>>();
            return maps;
        }
    }
}
```

Until now, I've implemented inside of it a dictionary, I supposed this is not the best performance. Ok, let me follow explaning you the scenario.

I've confgure it..

```
    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();
        ...
        Container.RegisterType<IExerciseMap, ExerciseMap>();
    }
```

And this is an example of a ModuleInit from one of the modules.

```
    public ModuleInit(IUnityContainer container, IRegionManager regionManager,
        IExerciseMap maps)
    {
        ...
        _maps = maps;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        // Add types to the mapping (this is right, no changes)
        _maps.Add(typeof(..), Func<...>);
        _maps.Add(typeof(..), Func<...>);
        ...
    }
```

And here I'm passing the value from the object (mapping in the constructor).

```
public class WorksheetViewModel : NotificationObject
{
    private readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<BaseItem, BaseItemViewModel>> maps;

    public WorksheetViewModel(..., Dictionary<Type, Func<BaseItem, BaseItemViewModel>> maps)
    {
        ...
        this.maps = maps;
    }
 }
```

As I said, I'm not convinced that this is a good idea and performance. Maybe I should just register an instance in the container of the mapping dictionary, what do you think?

Comment: I don't really understand where you are stuck.  I would, however, advise against *injecting* a dictionary.  Rather use a class that makes sense in your domain to wrap it.  Your `ExcerciseMap` class appears to perform that function.

Comment: I mean, I supposed that is not necessary what I'm doing. There's still another way to refactor this o improve it. I guess I'm being redundant